# WebGL Gradient Shader

Tags: webgl, shader, gradient

I am trying to learn WebGL and would like to have shader that gives a mesh a gradient effect from top to bottom. For example, the bottom of a ball or wall having no blue color and the top having all blue. I know I need to modify the fragment color with the y component of gl_Position but my implementations have thus far given me a black screen. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the fragments are getting actually drawn on the screen (disable culling, depth test), no GL errors ? If yes, only issue can be the Alpha setting with blending enabled. Try disabling GL_BLEND, or changing the value of Alpha to 1.0, like below, setting RGB to your colors:

> > gl_FragColor = vec4(R,G,B, 1.0);